# Is opencpu useful as an API called by a web service?

Tags: api, web-applications, opencpu, rapache, renjin

Hi `Opencpu` is a really cool tool. But now I want to use a Data Processing Unit (DPU) in a web-service.

Can it be used in a production environment where there are **lots** of requests which call r functions and scripts which only require a **short** amount of time to run?

Does it support **parallel** requests and **multiple R sessions**?

Would `deployR` or `yhatq` be a more favorable solution in such a case? Or would you recommend to go with `rserve` or `rapache` as they might require less overhead?

Or would you recommend to try `renjin` or `pqr` in such a situation as there will be far less latency as no HTTP requests (RTT) will need to be processed.

Re-implementing R packages as custom java or c/c++ code is not really an option due to time constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that http://www.renjin.org is way faster. But unfortunately does not yet support all R packages.